# how to handle redirection url in port forwarding - docker container

Tags: magento2, docker

I build **magento application** in docker container, I am trying to access that container from remote machine using `docker port forwarding`.

### System A

**create container :** `docker run -it -d -p 8000:80 -h tm.gworks.mobi -v /var/www/public --privileged --name testmachineone magedev`

**container ip :** `172.17.0.2`

**System A ip :** `192.168.1.6`

I can able to access webserver using both ip in **system A** `http://172.17.0.2` && `http://192.168.1.6:8000`

**note:** if I access `http://192.168.1.6:8000` it will get automatically redirect to `http://172.17.0.2` that is default behavior of magento.

### System B

if I access `http://192.168.1.6:8000` it will get automatically redirect to `http://172.17.0.2` but **system B** can't able to access `http://172.17.0.2`  so it throws 404 error..

as per my search we can't access docker container ip from remote host, only way is port forwarding. But I stuck with URL redirection in port forwarding.

is there any way to stop redirection in port forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can customize the `/etc/hosts` to simulate a **domain** on the two machines.